# What is the best way to censor inappropriate words that might contain markup within them?

Tags: php, regex, filter, spam

I run a large website that contains millions of user generated posts that contain HTML.  Some of these posts contain sensitive words my advertisers don't want to advertise next to.  Instead of deleting these posts, I'd rather censor out the "bad" words.  I also need to preserve the markup because letting the users mark up their posts is a major feature of the site.

I am currently using a search and replace with `str_ireplace()`, but our authors have become clever and are doing things (below) that slip through my primitive filter.  I can strip the tags and *detect* the inappropriate words, but am looking for a way of replacing the words while leaving the markup untouched.

Examples:

Successfully censored:

```
input:  "<p>Mary is a bitch.</p>"
output: "<p>Mary is a *****.</p>"
```

Unsuccessfully censored:

```
input:          "<p>Mary is a <strong>b</strong>itch.</p>"
failed output:  "<p>Mary is a <strong>b</strong>itch.</p>" 
desired output: "<p>Mary is a <strong>*</strong>****.</p>"
```

Comment: I don't think this will help. How about b-itch, b*i*t*c*h, beetch, be-yatch, etc, ad nauseam. It's a continuous battle where you add rules, and they find workarounds.

Comment: @SWeko - I have my word list -- the problem is that some authors are doing things like b<i>ee</i>tch of which there are infinite possibilities.

Comment: First of all, get rid of the html in your messages. There is really no way to reliably censor your text if that's in there. Then, strip all non-letter characters, then compare your result with a massive library of all possible swearwords. Good luck.

Comment: @Vidbot: Your wordlist is not helping you as SWeko showed.

Comment: @Cerbrus the HTML is a main feature and cannot be eliminated as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Don't forget unicode use as well, `Ɓitch` or `ʙitch` both of which do not use a regular `B`, then there are the numeric substitutions like `B1tch`. Something like this would not catch every possibility. You best bet is a good moderation system for reporting and removing offensive posts.

Comment: No, the possibilities are finite, but many :-) You would need to parse the markup to a DOM, and match your strings only against text nodes then.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - I have a list of words that Google and their AdWords users consider to be "sensitive".  It is by no means complete, but it contains the words I need to worry about.

Comment: @Vidbot: You could strip the string like I suggested, and reject it if it contains swearwords, and "accept" the original sting if it doesn't.

Comment: @Vidbot: So your advertisers don't want to advertise next to `bitch` but advertising next to `b1tch` or `Ɓitch` would be ok? Are you sure?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - "bitch" is an example.  Here is the word list I am working with: http://pastebin.com/MskvyKQ9 which was pulled in part from filtering done by Google in their "what do you love" page: wdyl.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun here is a quick and dirty way:

```
$badWords = array('bitch', 'jerk');
$input = '<p>Mary is a <strong>b</strong>itch. </p>';

$arr = explode(' ', $input);

foreach($arr as $key => $word)
{
    $word = str_replace('.', '', strip_tags($word));
    if(in_array($word, $badWords))
    {
        $arr[$key] = '*****';
    }
}

$output = implode(' ', $arr);
echo $output;
```

Output

```
<p>Mary is a ***** </p>
```

The above splits the text into words, and applies `strip_tags()` on each of the words, so that it doesn't affect the entire content.

There are still many ways around it though, as the comments point out. You'll never get a perfect solution that can handle everything they throw at it - you would need to create something close to artificial intelligence. I think the best real solution would be to `strip_tags()` on the whole post and search for the bad words, then if any found, flag the post for moderator attention. Or just simply have a report post system with active moderators.

Comment: This problem has become time-sensitive so I think I'm going to have to do a mass search and flag all posts that contain bad words and have the mods deal with them.

Comment: @Vidbot then, you should  post this comment as an answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to use other methods to stop this, as it is extremely hard.

from [this amusing piece by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html) about what 'clbuttic' problems arise from trying to do so:

> Obscenity filtering is an enduring, maybe even timeless problem. I'm doubtful it will ever be possible to solve this particular problem through code alone. But it seems some companies and developers can't stop tilting at that windmill. Which means you might want to think twice before you move to Scunthorpe.

Comment: I currently have a few mods flagging and deleting posts, but may need to find more easily offended mods to align with the views of Google's ad network.

Answer (score 0):

You could start from a "bad words" list and check the tag-clean string (that is, filtered via [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) against the "bad words".
Then you could iterate each bad word through a series of possible single-letter alterations, eg `S=>5, 1=>L, 0=>O` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have an extremely tough time accomplishing this in your way, but my recommendation would be to not change the words out with asterisks, but rather just reject the posting and let the user know why. Here's why:

1. **Simplify your searching.** If your algorithm only has to check if some form of a bad word exists in the text, then you can `strip_tags` the text and search for your words. If you were to try to replace this out with asterisks, you can't `strip_tags` since you need to leave the originating text in it's prior condition.
2. **It's what people expect.** What people *don't* expect is for their text to be modified with no notification to them. You'd likely be better sending people back with a message that says "this post contains inappropriate words/text"

If you are insistent that you replace with asterisks instead of sending the user back, you'll need to write a basic character-by-character parser that ignores HTML tags and constructs words out of it.